# Embed a docker image in the rootfs

Tags: docker, yocto, bitbake, tensorrt

I would like to embed a docker image in the rootfs for an Nvidia Jetson using yocto dunfell. I know that I could embed the docker tarball image in the rootfs and load it during the first boot with `docker load`, but I would like to have the image available since the first boot. I succeeded in doing it for generic images like alpine:

- I defined a recipe where I initialized the docker daemon on a folder in the work directory
- I pulled the image with `docker pull --platform linux/arm64 alpine:latest`
- Finally I copied the files to the rootfs.

I tried to do the same thing with the TensorRT image (just replace the docker pull line with `docker pull --platform linux/arm64 nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-tensorrt:r8.2.1-runtime`) but I got symlinks errors (I checked and in fact there were links that points to themselfs). I guessed that it was a bug of the image and since I tested it outside yocto I decided to add a command to delete corrupted symlinks (`find ${DOCKER_STORE}/overlay2 -type l -exec sh -c 'for x; do [ -e "$x" ] || rm "$x"; done' _ {} +`). Now everything compiles but I got an error during the final `do_rootfs` stage:

```
ERROR: image-app-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/media/disk1/tegra-demo-distro/build/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit_emmc-oe4t-linux/image-app/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /media/disk1/tegra-demo-distro/build/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit_emmc-oe4t-linux/image-app/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/media/disk1/tegra-demo-distro/build/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit_emmc-oe4t-linux/image-app/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/media/disk1/tegra-demo-distro/build/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit_emmc-oe4t-linux/image-app/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/media/disk1/tegra-demo-distro/build/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit_emmc-oe4t-linux/image-app/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/media/disk1/tegra-demo-distro/build/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit_emmc-oe4t-linux/image-app/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --nogpgcheck install cuda-libraries docker-app-image gstreamer1.0-omx-tegra gstreamer1.0-plugins-nvvideo4linux2 nvidia-docker packagegroup-base-extended packagegroup-core-boot packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh packagegroup-demo-base packagegroup-demo-basetests packagegroup-demo-systemd run-postinsts tensorrt-core locale-base-en-us locale-base-en-gb' returned 1:
DNF version: 4.2.2
cachedir: /media/disk1/tegra-demo-distro/build/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit_emmc-oe4t-linux/image-app/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
Added oe-repo repo from /media/disk1/tegra-demo-distro/build/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit_emmc-oe4t-linux/image-app/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
not found other for: 
not found modules for: 
not found deltainfo for: 
not found updateinfo for: 
oe-repo: using metadata from Wed 28 Jun 2023 02:23:05 PM UTC.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Wed 28 Jun 2023 02:23:05 PM UTC.
No module defaults found
--> Starting dependency resolution
--> Finished dependency resolution
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides /usr/bin/perl5.26-aarch64-linux-gnu needed by docker-app-image-1.0-r0.aarch64
  - nothing provides /usr/bin/python needed by docker-app-image-1.0-r0.aarch64
  - nothing provides /usr/bin/python2 needed by docker-app-image-1.0-r0.aarch64
  - nothing provides /usr/bin/python2.7 needed by docker-app-image-1.0-r0.aarch64
  - nothing provides /usr/bin/python3.6 needed by docker-app-image-1.0-r0.aarch64
  - nothing provides libcupti.so.10.2()(64bit) needed by docker-app-image-1.0-r0.aarch64
  - nothing provides libcupti.so.10.2(libcupti.so.10.2)(64bit) needed by docker-app-image-1.0-r0.aarch64
  - nothing provides libgfortran-daac5196.so.5.0.0(GFORTRAN_8)(64bit) needed by docker-app-image-1.0-r0.aarch64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /media/disk1/tegra-demo-distro/build/tmp/work/jetson_nano_devkit_emmc-oe4t-linux/image-app/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.416411
ERROR: Task (/media/disk1/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta-app/recipes-core/images/image-app.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

Here is the recipe (heavily inspired from [here](https://blog.savoirfairelinux.com/en-ca/2020/how-to-embed-a-docker-image-into-yoctos-root-filesystem/)):

```
DESCRIPTION = "Container images installation"
LICENSE = "Proprietary"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/Proprietary;md5=0557f9d92cf58f2ccdd50f62f8ac0b28"

DOCKER_STORE = "${WORKDIR}/docker-store"

inherit systemd
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "container-image.service"
SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_${PN} = "enable"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "docker bash mount-noauto python3"

SRC_URI = "file://container-image.service \
           file://container-image.sh \
          "

do_pull_image[nostamp] = "1"
do_package_qa[noexec] = "1"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN}_append = "already-stripped"
EXCLUDE_FROM_SHLIBS = "1"

do_pull_image() {
    [ -n "$(/usr/bin/pidof dockerd)" ] && sudo kill "$(/usr/bin/pidof dockerd)" && sleep 5

    [ -d "${DOCKER_STORE}" ] && sudo rm -rf "${DOCKER_STORE}"/*

    [ -n "$(/usr/bin/pidof dockerd)" ] && sudo kill "$(/usr/bin/pidof dockerd)"
    sudo /usr/bin/dockerd --data-root "${DOCKER_STORE}" &


    # Wait a little before pulling to let the daemon be ready.
    sleep 5

    if ! sudo docker info; then
        bbfatal "Error launching docker daemon"
    fi

    # sudo docker pull --platform linux/arm64 alpine:latest
    sudo docker pull --platform linux/arm64 nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-tensorrt:r8.2.1-runtime

    sudo find ${DOCKER_STORE}/overlay2 -type l -exec sh -c 'for x; do [ -e "$x" ] || rm "$x"; done' _ {} +

    sudo chown -R "${USER}" "${DOCKER_STORE}"

    # Clean temporary folders in the docker store.
    rm -rf "${DOCKER_STORE}/runtimes"
    rm -rf "${DOCKER_STORE}/tmp"

    # Kill dockerd daemon after use.
    sudo kill "$(/usr/bin/pidof dockerd)"
}

do_install() {
    install -d "${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system"
    install -m 0644 "${WORKDIR}/container-image.service" "${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/"

    install -d "${D}${bindir}"
    install -m 0755 "${WORKDIR}/container-image.sh" "${D}${bindir}/container-image"

    install -d "${D}${localstatedir}/lib/docker"
    cp -R "${DOCKER_STORE}"/* "${D}${localstatedir}/lib/docker/"
}

FILES_${PN} = "\
    ${system_unitdir}/system/container-image.service \
    ${bindir}/container-image \
    ${localstatedir}/lib/docker \
    "

addtask pull_image before do_install after do_fetch

REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES= "systemd"
```